# Обработка событий мышки

Tags: java, swing

не могу словить событие прокрутки колесика мышки (события нажатия, перемещения на обычных кнопках словил без проблем).
Собственно колесико мышки у меня должно использоваться как zoom. Т.е. словив событие мне еще хотелось бы как-то узнать на сколько изменилось колесико с исходного положения.

```
protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL) {
        System.out.println("покажи мне что-нибудь")
    }
```

По идее код должен выглядеть как-то так, но он не работает >.< Может кто подскажет или закидает толковыми ссылками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL
```

тут нечего подозрительного не видишь?

Comment: не вижу, увы
при обработке кода  
    
    evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED
или  
     
    evt.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED
ловит всё как надо

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html - решение, если не разберешься, спрашивай еще =)

Comment: точно, как всегда забыл офф доки глянуть) лучи добра тебе), все работает на ура)